# Subversion post commit hook checkout to website document root

Tags: linux, svn, hook

We have Subversion running on our Debian development server.

We have setup a post-commit hook to checkout the contents of the repository to /var/www/ourwebsite

There are about 2GB worth of files and each checkout takes about 10-15 minutes.

If we are simply changing a couple lines of code, it will continually keep copying files over and over, I dont think this is the right approach.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `svn update` instead of `svn checkout`

Make sure that you have Apache setup to ignore svn files

Comment: +1. for the same task, I do updates and do it locally using a production working copy first obtained by `svn co file:///repo/path`